# How is this commutator property $[a,b]=bx$ called?

Tags: terminology, noncommutative-algebra

If two elements $a,b$ commute like this  $[a,b]=bx$ for some $x$ so that it can rewriten as
$$
ba=a(b-x),
$$
is  there a term for such property? It is as if $a$ and $b$ almost commuted (but not quite) with $x=0$ a special case.

Comment: If $x$ is proportional to $a$, then this commutation relation defines the quantum plane: $ab = qba$, or $[a,b]=ab-ba=(q-1)ba$.  I don't know if it has a special name in general.

Comment: What if $x$ is just a complex number?

Comment: Don't know.  Seems like it arises for exponentials of operators, for instance.  E.g., $[\partial_x, e^{kx}] = ke^{kx}$.